# JToolBarHelper::addNew() and create button

Tags: joomla

Can anyone tell me how to use JToolBarHelper::addNew();

What should i do to make it work inside admin view?

Nothing happened when i click on create button

Comment: You can improve your question by including evidence of research (links to sites/pages that were similar but not completely effective) and showing your best coding attempt.  Adding context helps future researchers to better relate their issue with yours.  More content in your question body will help search engines to find this page when researchers are seeking this type of support.  Right now, your question says: I tried something, but it failed. Can someone spoon feed me?  Stackoverflow would appreciate a better post from you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a task + function behind it between brackets.
See https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_toolbar_for_your_component

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew(string $task, string $alt, boolean  $check);
// Will call the task/function $task in your controller
```

For example, Joomla's com_content Articles /administrator/components/com_content/views/articles/view.html.php uses

```
JToolbarHelper::addNew('article.add');
```

Its Article Controller /administrator/components/com_content/controllers/article.php 
extends FormController (previously called JControllerForm), and that parent class has a method called add() that will be used.

btw: since Joomla 3.8 you can use namespacing and change JToolbarHelper to

```
use Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\ToolbarHelper;

ToolbarHelper::addNew(string $task, string $alt, boolean  $check);
```

Comment: If you have Joomla expertise to share, please create a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account and help us to resolve open questions and curate great content.